# Selecting or activating existing Excel chart

Tags: python, excel, charts

I use python 2.7.3 and Windows7.

1. I want to decorate the Excel chart by using Python.
   It's not necessary to make charts from start to end.
2. First step(EXCEL STEP), I store data in the Excel sheet and make line chart roughly.
   (by selecting data range and using hot-key 'ALT+N+N+enter')
3. Next step(PYTHON STEP), I want to modify chart made in first step.
   Specifically border line color and width, chart size, label fonts, fonts size and so on.

   How can I select or activate existing Excel chart by Python?(Not create chart from Python)

Comment: You mean you need a python module to help you?

Comment: Yes. After searching regarding my question, I knew xlsxwriter or win32com may helpful for me. However any documentations don't explained how to activate existing charts.(They say only how to create charts.) So, I hope to know how to select or activate existing charts. Any python modules doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that all the python module could only create excels but not activate existing charts. Try `xlrd` and `xlwt`. Good luck.